# How do I add the symbol \textsection in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

> I would like to add the symbol \textsection in the table of contents, How can I do that?, I'm using the AMSBook class.

[image]

The above picture show that standard table of contents with the AMSBook class only putting \tableofcontents, but without the \textsection.

Comment: Please give us a short minimum working example of code that shows the problem, to save us the time of recreating it from scratch.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the picture is the standard table of contents, the only difference thing is that has \textsection. So it's just the \tableofcotents command.

Comment: I am asking for you to type it in and show the code in your question, so we don't have to... You are asking for help from unpaid volunteers.  It would be a common courtesy for you to provide them with all necessary to minimize the time they need to spend.  At least that is the philosophy that we ask on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a question of changing `\tocsection` to add `\S` in front of the second argument.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tocsection[3]{%
  \indentlabel
  {\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ignorespaces #1 \S#2.\quad }}#3%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{First part}

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

[image]